# Extracting Vertices / Snapping to points from Vector Tile Service (VTS) Layer

Tags: qgis, snapping, vector-tiles, feature-extraction

I am using a new vector tile service for background mapping.

I can select/interrogate individual objects from the vector layer with the info tool - but they're not recognised by the snapping tool.

I wanted to be able to snap to the vertices from the VTS layer when creating my own layers on top.

Any ideas/suggestions very welcome!

[image: QGIS Screenshot]

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing the current settings of your snapping tool.

Comment: Thanks Erik - added above!

Comment: And which layer are you trying to snap to?

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. 

I was looking to use snapping to create new polygons in a shapefile layer. 

Have found a limited workaround… not ideal, but helps a little.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the design principles of native vector tile support from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/162

Vector tiles are placed on a special vector tile layer and geometries do not behave like true vectors. I guess that's why you can't snap to vector tile features.

> A big problem with representation of vector tiles as vector layers is
> that they are not "proper" vector layers. Vector tiles are data that
> have been modified for efficient visualization, making compromises
> elsewhere:
>
> Geometries have been split, clipped, simplified, features may have
> been filtered out altogether at some zoom levels. Having a polygon in
> one vector tile, we do not know if that is the complete representation
> of the feature or if the feature continues in some adjacent (or
> distant!) tiles. We cannot find a feature by its ID - we would need to
> browse through all tiles. We do not know how many features there are
> or cannot show attribute table of the whole sub-layer without fetching
> all tiles. All of these limitations of vector tiles come from the idea
> to make their rendering as fast as possible. We should not try to use
> them for other than display purposes. It is better to think of the
> data encoded in vector tiles as raw data for map renderer, not "true"
> vector data for analysis or other common GIS uses.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That makes a lot of sense. 

After playing around I’ve found a workaround, but it’s pretty hacky. 

It’s possible to select the optimised vector objects and copy to a scratch layer - and then snap to those vertices. 

Not ideal, but can be helpful tracing around complex geometry.